# Angular transclude/replace equivalent in UI-Router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router

I have just started using angular `ui-router`.

I wanted to know, when i am specifying a `templateUrl`, i can see that the template is injected into the element of the `ui-view`, for example:

```
<div ui-view="myState"></div>

.state('myState', {
        url: '/myState',
        templateUrl: 'partials/my-state.html'      
    })
```

Results in:

```
<div ui-view="myState">
    <section class"ex1 exa">
        <p>Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</p>
    </section>
</div>
```

When what i am after is:

```
    <section class"ex1 exa">
        <p>Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</p>
    </section>
```

So essentially the `<div ui-view="myState">` has been replaced.

I know within directives, you can use transclude and replace, does the ui-router have such an ability within it?

Comment: why do you want to do this?

Comment: @LionC because its adding necessary markup

Comment: Did you mean "unnecessary"? Because no developer ever sees that unnecessary markup.

Comment: @LionC sorry, yes, unnecessary

Comment: Then dont bother. It does not matter for development or for performance, but changing it would make debugging harder because it is unclear where the routing views are.

Comment: I've just come across this, it affects CSS. It's adding an un-necessary div and the css is trying to turn the child divs into a grid system, because there's only one div, there's only one column.